# How to get a drupal path in a modal form?

Tags: chaos-tool-suite, javascript

I would like to have a specific path in a modal form. I tried several things but cannot get i work.

**Modal_form**

I installed the module, clear cached and added into a body tekst the example of the module:

```
<a class="ctools-use-modal ctools-modal-modal-popup-large" href="node/2">Link to click</a>
```

When I click on this link I will get ajax error 200.

**Colorbox** and **Colorbox Node**

Maybe it is working with this module...installed module. After installation I Enabled the Colorbox load option and clear cache.Put the below link in a body text.

```
<p><a class="colorbox-load" href="node/2?width=500& height=500">colorbox test</a></p>
```

After clicking the link I will see node/2 in the browser but not in a modal form.
The filters in the editor is full html

**Ctools automodal module**

Installed the module. Put node/2 into the extra modal links box. Pushed the submit button but it is not saved

So probable I do something not good but what? Any suggestion?
Using chrome.

Console errors: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/ with jquery

Any investigation says that this is a ajax call but I'n not sure.

set jquery update to 1.9 for front end. But no luck :-(

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

you want to display node on popup I guess. The modal form itself does not provide node to display on popup. You need create custom module for it and set its template page.

If you are using colorbox there is one module [colorbox node](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox_node) which provides you built in setting to display node on popup.

only need to set `class="colorbox-node"`.

Comment: installed colorbox-node. Same result as colorbox module. Seeing page but not in modal form.